# [C++]Covariant return types

Tags: c++, virtual

I have a `VectorN` class, and a `Vector3` class inherited from `VectorN` (which can handle cross products for example). I have trouble determining the return types of the different operators. Example:

```
class VectorN
{
public:
   VectorN(){};
   virtual VectorN operator*(const double& d) {.....};
   std::vector<double> coords;
};

class Vector3 : public VectorN
{
public:
  Vector3(){};
  virtual Vector3 operator*(const double& d) {....};
};
```

This particular example produces a C2555 error:

> 'Vector3::operator *': overriding virtual function return type differs and is not covariant from 'VectorN::operator *', see declaration of 'VectorN::operator *'.

The problem is that I don't return a reference to a `Vector3`, and that the `Vector3` class is not fully defined at the declaration of the `operator*`. However, I want my `operator*` to be virtual, and I want to return a `Vector3` when I multiply a `Vector3` with a constant (otherwise, if I do `(Vector3*double).crossProduct(Vector3)`, it would return an error).

What can I do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the way to replace an object with a pointer is `auto_ptr`/`unique_ptr`, but those can't be covariant! X-P .

Comment: By the way, don't pass primitives by `const&`, do it by value. (Don't pass any primitive by `const&` or anything which has a size less than `sizeof(void*)`.)

Comment: Now that I've answered the question… why aren't you using a ready-made numerics library? This functionality is even in the standard as `valarray`.

Comment: Because the goal of the class is not to only do crossProducts and multiplications. In the vector3 class there are color conversion functions or to random sample vectors with different pdf etc.. Not a kind of generic use.

Comment: @user: Those things should be free-functions. *Always* prefer free functions.

Comment: @user: Such functionality is built atop a library such as `valarray` (or any of dozens of free alternatives). Reimplementing vectors and dot products starts you down a wrong path and it will be hard to turn around. And, generating random vectors or converting color-spaces should be free functions (outside the class), not methods. A class is not a library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a re-design. First, prefer free-functions over member-functions. The only member functions you should have are the ones that need access to privates.

Start with this combo:

```
class VectorN
{
public:
   virtual VectorN& operator*=(double d)
    {
        /* ... */

        return *this;
    };
};


class Vector3 : public VectorN
{
public:
    virtual Vector3& operator*=(double d)
    {
        return static_cast<Vector3&>(VectorN::operator*=(d));
    };
};
```

Here covariance works fine because the type is a reference or pointer, and you re-use code. (`static_cast` is free, performance-wise, and safe since you know the derived type.)

Then you implement your free-functions:

```
// optimization: if you're going to make a copy, do it in the parameter list;
// compilers can elide a copy when working with temporaries
VectorN operator*(VectorN v, double d)
{
    // reuse code
    return v *= d;
}

VectorN operator*(double d, VectorN v)
{
    // reuse code
    return v *= d;
}
```

Do the same with `Vector3`.

What's been done is you get an *easy* way to write these operators because you get to use the core of the operator, and the return type matches, thanks to covariance.

---

Do heed warnings though, you probably don't need any of it. And extensions you want to make can be made via free-functions operating on a `vector` or `valarray`.

Comment: Or… just use `valarray`. Having both `vectorN` and `vector3` suggests he wants a algebraic vector library templated over size. Do you know of an easy one?

Comment: +1: Very nice! One thing though, when you say "Make `v` above `const VectorN` to allow `Vector3` to use it..." did you miss an ampersand? Presumably the argument needs to be a reference to avoid slicing and the loss of virtual dispatch on `*=`?

Comment: @Troubador: No, he is suggesting pass and return by value, and duplicating all the functions. Really this is a problem for templates.

Comment: @Troubadour: Yes, but on second glance it's senseless.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your answers! I think I'll opt for this solution, at least for operators. :)

Comment: mmm... but for functions which are not operator, I don't really like to write getNormalized(myVector3) instead of myVector3.getNormalized() which seems more natural :s

Comment: @WhiteAngl: It's something you have to get used to. The vector should only expose methods for manipulating and accessing the data on the most fundamental level. Your naming scheme effects this too; I would name it `normalized`, as in `Vector3 r = normalized(v);`, which reads quite natural. (And yes, this implies the standard library is poorly designed.)

Answer (score 0):

The best I can think of is to replace the return type with a smart pointer and forgo covariance in favor of polymorphism:

```
virtual auto_ptr< VectorN > operator*(const double& d);
```

The reason I suggest this is that you are using virtual functions, so knowing the exact type of the object isn't necessary anyway.

The underlying problem is that the caller needs to allocate storage for an object returned by value. That storage cannot vary dynamically, so you are inevitably stuck allocating the object on the heap.

Comment: I'm not familiar with auto_ptr but I'll look at that... Thanks! :)