# Automatic covariant class derivations

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++11

What is the neatest way of having a class like this,

```
class Object
{
public:
    virtual Object* Find(string name);
};
```

implemented so that its derived classes' `Find()` method automatically returns the derived class type without having to do something like this:

```
class DerivedObject : public Object
{
public:
    DerivedObject* Find(string name);
};
```

manually?

**Extra:** actually in my real implementation it's a bunch of `static` functions, not `virtual` ones. I've got functions like `static Object* Object::Find(string name)` and `static GameObject* GameObject::Find(string name)`.

Comment: I believe you are out of luck

Comment: Hmm... not even through templates, somehow?

Comment: The whole point of making `Find` virtual is so you can have a reference to an `Object` to call `Find` on. But that necessarily means you'll be expecting `Find` to return an `Object`, not a `DerivedObject`.

Comment: Well, I disagree, since it's part of the language that there's covariant types to make the above not an override but a virtual override.

Comment: The problem with doing that is that if you derive some object from the `Object` class, there's no guarantee that `DerivedObject::objects` is a vector containing only `DerivedObject` pointers. That vector could very easily still contain `Object` pointers, as its declared type is `vector<Object*>` regardless

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Yes, it's legal to do what you're doing, but it only works if `DerivedObject::Find` is explicitly defined. The compiler won't guess. The closest you can get with templates is the CRTP, which will do what you ask, but `Object` becomes `Object<DerivedObject>` and that may or may not fit with the rest of your code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: It should be possible to do something like this, but you'll probably have to get rid of the virtual function.  And there are situations where you'll be forced to make some things `const`.

Comment: Do you really need `Object` to contain a vector of `Object*`, and `DerivedObject` to contain a vector of `DerivedObject*`?  Wouldn't it make more sense to have a `BaseContainer` that contains a vector of `Base*` and a `DerivedContainer` that contains a vector of `Derived*`?  If so, please edit your question.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato Take a look here: [Get derived type via base class virtual function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501838/get-derived-type-via-base-class-virtual-function/19503045#19503045). I've tried to explain (and discussed) the problem in depth there.

Comment: What is your end goal here?

Comment: @Aaron: Edited because the vector of objects was really superfluous.

Comment: @Jefffrey, I want to not have to type four variants of this `Find()` function (Find, FindAll, etc...) for every derived type that I create from `Object`. Something like the above would be very handy.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato,  I still find it strange that each `Object` has a method that can return an `Object*`?  Do you expect to be able to the following: do `Object object; object->Find("a")->Find("b")->Find("c")`?  Do you want a recursive objects-containing-objects-containing-objects-... structure?  Or perhaps this is a *Singleton* object where each `Object` has access to *all* `Objects`?  So I ask again: maybe you want `ObjectContainer :: Find` returning `Object&`, and `DerivedContainer :: Find` return `Derived*`?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid, actually in my real implementation it's a bunch of static functions, not virtual ones, so it would fit in better with what you've said. I've got functions like `static Object* Object::Find(string name)` and `static GameObject* GameObject::Find(string name)`. My first guess here was to use virtual functions for a more general sort of problem, which wouldn't work with static functions, so it's not precisely the same thing.

Comment: @Adam Thanks, the CRTP pattern looks more like what I had in mind.

Comment: @KristianD'Amato, I've copied that comment into the question.  I think it's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `virtual` function, and write a free function instead.

```
template<typename T>
T* Find(T& object, string name) {
}
```

You'll have to call it via `Find(derivedobject,name)` instead of `derivedobject.Find(name)`, but otherwise I think this will behave as you like.

You'll also have to declare this as a `friend` inside `Object` if you need it to have access to the `protected` data.  Just put the following line inside the `Object` class.

```
template<typename T>
friend
T* Find(T& object, string);
```