# Send information to Maya node instance in cpp

Tags: c++, plugins, nodes, maya

I am currently developing a Maya plug-in in cpp. From the main class, I create a custom node instance (MPxLocatorNode) using the MDagModifier createNode command.

However, how can I pass information (a bunch of floats) to this custom node so that it takes them into account and acts upon it ?
I believe the plugs will help me, but I have no clue where to start: In the main class, how to link a plug to the instance and in the instance how to receive the plugs knowing that compute doesn't seem to be used as the instance does not have any input.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this based on code that you shared in your previous question?

Comment: If you're not using compute, you can just use the regular maya.cmds api to create and set custom attributes.

Comment: kartikg3: Yes, this is correct. theodox: Can I do this from one main class to a node instance created by this main class ?

Comment: So you're not inheriting from `MPxLocatorNode`? I don't think you're using the Maya API as it was intended. What is it that you're trying to do? The question is very unclear.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637438/how-to-get-node-class-instance-from-mobject-in-maya-api) is the question mentioned before.