# What does it mean to change the arguments of a virtual function in the derived classes?

Tags: c++

Changing the return type is prohibited.

However, what does changing the argument mean? Does it mean:

1. The virtual function is being rightfully redefined/overridden as it was intended to be.

   or
2. The virtual function is not being redefined/overridden but is actually being overloaded in the derived class. As a result, if the virtual function were pure, the derived class is still abstract.

Is it 1 or 2 or something else?

Comment: It would help to have the context in which these quotes were found.

Comment: I put the quotes for better readability. This is something that just popped up in my mind.

Comment: What I mean to say is what happens if the derived class changes the arguments of a base class virtual function instead of overriding it?  What are the implications?

Comment: btw, you are allowed to change the return type when you override a function, but you have to do so covariantly.

Comment: I know but you can't change the return types of virtual functions in the derived classes I believe?

Comment: Yes you can, that's what I was trying to say.

Comment: @Grendan You already read this Q&A? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516889/covariant-return-types

Comment: It would be really easy to test this.

Comment: Oh....I copy paste this from the notes I was provided: `A redefined virtual function can not differ from the original only by the return type.`

Answer (score 3):

> Changing the return type is prohibited

Nope, covariant return types are fine. Eg.

```
struct A {};
struct B: public A {};
struct X {
  virtual A& foo() { return a; }
  A a;
};
struct Y: public X {
  B& foo() override { return b; }
  B b;
};
int main() {
  return sizeof(Y);
}
```

Changing anything else in the prototype, including the parameter list, will indeed result in an overload rather than an override. You can easily verify this with the 'override' specifier.

As Ben Voigt points out, the "parameter list" here means whatever you declare *minus* any top-level cv-qualification. That is, both these functions are considered to have the same type:

```
void foo(int, const char *);
void bar(const int, const char * const);
```

Comment: I was referring to the virtual functions. I don't know what covariant means but I read somewhere that virtual functions in the base class cannot have their return types changed in the derived classes.Please clarify on this.

Comment: @Grendan: What's there to clarify? He's saying that your statement is wrong. No need to repeat your wrong statement. :)

Comment: ... except that top-level cv-qualifiers on parameters are not part of the function signature, so "everything else" doesn't include those

Answer (score 1):

> *"Changing the return type is prohibited."*

That assumption is wrong, for the general case.

> *"2. The virtual function is not being redefined/overridden but is actually being overloaded in the derived class. As a result, if the virtual function were pure, the derived class is still abstract."*
>
> *"Is it 1 or 2 or something else?"*

It's 2.

Changing the signature of a function by adding/changing parameter(s)/types will no longer match the pure `virtual` function signature provided by the abstract base class.

So yes. The derived class doesn't provide an implementation for the pure `virtual` function declaration, as inherited from the base class, hence it's still abstract, yes.

Comment: That's for confirming by gut feeling.

Comment: @Grendan _"That's for confirming by gut feeling."_ No. I'm pretty sure! Are you asking about the [tag:language-lawyer] confirmations? THis would take a minute or two.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I think he meant "_my_ gut feeling".

Comment: My bad. Yeah, that's what I mean..@LightningRacisinObrit is smart.

Comment: @Grendan _"@LightningRacisinObrit is smart"_ Sure she is!

Answer (score 0):

It is overloaded. The arguments are part of the function signature. And yes, remains abstract.