# Overriding typedefs in C++

Tags: c++

I have a generic struct

```
template<typename X, typename Y>
struct S
{

};
```

Then there is an abstract class which returns shared pointer to above struct in a pure virtual function. One of the derived classes also implements this function but needs to return pointer to S with different instantiated type:

```
typedef boost::shared_pointer<S<double, double>> BPtr;
class BaseClass
{
  public:
    BPtr Func() = 0;
};

typedef boost::shared_pointer<S<double, std::tuple<double, double>>>    Dptr;
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
   public:
      DPtr Func() {}
}
```

Ideally I would like to be able to return an override typedef in the derived class but can't do that in C++.

How do I fix this dilemma?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to typedef a function.

Comment: You can override (localize) typedef by moving them into the class.  But C++ requires virtual functions to have the same signature and the return type is part of the signature.  What is your real question?

Comment: How would you use this function given a pointer to BaseClass?

Comment: Calling `base->Func()` on a `BaseClass*` needs to give you a `BPtr`. A `DPtr` is not a `BPtr`. How do you expect this to work? Just make a `Func2()`?

Comment: It is a design question. Functionality wise the Func() does very similar thing in both base and derived class. In fact that is the reason to have an abstract base class because all it's derived classes are doing similar but subtly different things. I would like to avoid creating another function but will do that as last resort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override a member function with different return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8967303/override-a-member-function-with-different-return-type)

Comment: "does very similar thing" Sorting an array of ints is very similar to sorting an array of doubles. Maybe you need a template.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the smart pointers: They don't have a common baseclass (just as `vector<baseclass>` is not a baseclass of `vector<derived>`), so covariant return types won't work.

Secondly, even if you replaced the smart pointers with raw pointers, different instantiations of a class template don't share a common base either (like vector and smart pointers), so you're out of luck.

Note that different instantiations of class templates can actually derive from one another, so if `S<double,double>` was a baseclass for `S<double,tuple<double,double>>`, you could use covariant returns, but that seems like a wonky approach.

In summary, I think you should describe why you think that an `S<T,tuple<T,T>>` could be treated like an `S<T,T>`, which seems the underlying assumption in your code.

Comment: S<T, tuple<T,T>> is an extension on S<T,T> as it treats the variable created with the second type as a pair. In future I may have need to treat variables of both first and second types as different data structures but the underlying algorithm in which they are used is very similar. To give more context to the question, you can think of S as a node in a tree which is encapsulating certain features of the tree in which it will be used. The features vary from tree to tree.

Comment: My gut feeling says this approach is brittle but you could have a  valid approach nonetheless. Questions/suggestions: As far as types are concerned, isn't `S` a template like `tuple`? Now, what you can do is to use type traits to partially specialize `S` so that `S<T1,T2>` with `T2` being a tuple like `S<T3,T4>` itself then derives from `S<T1,T3>`. However, also consider using variadic templates and `S<T1,T2,T3>` as extension to `S<T1,T2>`. I'd have to dive much deeper into your design and desires in order to give a definitive answer though. Happy hacking!

Comment: Yes, something like that might work. I'll look into variadic templates as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever `DerivedClass::Func` returns must be a subtype of what `BaseClass::Func` returns. Otherwise, `DerivedClass` is obviously **not** a specialization of `BaseClass`.

What makes you build this inheritance relationship in the first place? Without it, you could just make the return type of `Func` a template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you probably meant to make `Base::Func()` a `virtual` member function.

```
class BaseClass
{
  public:
    virtual BPtr Func() = 0;
 // ^^^ Missing 
};
```

Re:

> Ideally I would like to be able to return an override `typedef` in the derived class but can't do that in C++.

You can override the `typedef` in the derived class but that does not necessarily make it a valid return type of the `virtual` member function.

For instance, if I have:

```
struct Foo
{
   typedef int return_type;

   virtual return_type func() = 0;
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
   typedef double return_type;

   virtual return_type func() override { return 1.0; }
};
```

You should get a compiler error. Just because I use `return_type` in both the base class and the derived class does not make them suitable to be used as the return type of the `virtual` member function.

The return type in an overridden implementation can be [covariant type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3516889/covariant-return-types), not any old type. A `typedef` is just an alias. It's not a true type.

Re:

> How do I fix this dilemma?

You'll have to rethink your return types. You cannot use `boost::shared_pointer<S<double, std::tuple<double, double>>>` for the return type in the derived class when the return type in the base class is `boost::shared_pointer<S<double, double>>`.

Answer (score 0):

An (abstract) base class with virtual functions is used to provide the interface for the derived classes. You cannot have the same function return different (more precisily non-covariant) things depending on the derived type because the user has a contract with the base class.

If I have a

```
Base * p = /* get whatever derived instance here */;
```

it might very well be the case that I cannot even tell what actual derived type is hidden behind the pointer.

Therefore, if `Func` is declared as

```
boost::shared_ptr<S<double, double>> Func();
```

I'd expect it to return `boost::shared_ptr<S<double, double>>` and not something that depends on the actual derived type.

The reason is simple: If some derived type would be added that returns something that is incompatible with my code it would break my implementation with**out** the interface being changed at all.

It would work however, if `S<double, std::tuple<double, double>>` would derive from `S<double, double>`.

You cannot get around that restriction with typedefs because they are just alias names for the types they refer to. With a typedef like `using BPtr = boost::shared_ptr<S<double, double>>;`, this declaration:

```
BPtr foo();
```

is equivalent to

```
boost::shared_ptr<S<double, double>> foo();
```

it is just less typing involved if the typedef is used repeatedly.